# Executing AWS Signv4 HTTP API from Javascript returns 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I'm developing a Javascript (browser) client for HTTP API's in AWS API Gateway.The API's use an IAM authorizer. In my Javascript App I log in through a Cognito Identity Pool (developer identity). Next I convert the OpenID token into an access key id, secret access key and session token using AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials.

I then want to use these credentials to make the API call, using the code below. I see the call being executed, but I get a HTTP/403 error back. The reply does not contain any further indication of the cause. I'd appreciate all help to understand what is going wrong. When disabling the IAM authorizer, the HTTP API works nicely.

I also tried the JWT authorizer, passing the OpenID token received from the Cognito Identity Pool (using http://cognito-identity.amazon.com as provider). When doing so I get the error: `Bearer scope="" error="invalid_token" error_description="unable to decode "n" from RSA public key"` in the `www-authenticate` response header.

Thanks a lot.

```js
        // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
        var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
        var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
        var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

        let test_url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/yyyyyy';

        var httpRequest = new AWS.HttpRequest("https://" + test_url, "eu-central-1");
        httpRequest.method = "GET";

        AWS.config.credentials = {
            accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: sessionToken
        }



        var v4signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(httpRequest, "execute-api");
        v4signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, AWS.util.date.getDate());

         fetch(httpRequest.endpoint.href , {
            method: httpRequest.method,
            headers: httpRequest.headers,
            //body: httpRequest.body
        }).then(function (response) {
             if (!response.ok) {
                 $('body').html("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(response.blob()));
                 return;
             }
             $('body').html("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(response.blob()));
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging and searching the web, I found the solution. Generating a correct signature seems to require a 'host' header:

```js
httpRequest.headers.host = 'xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
```

After adding this host header the API call succeeds.